# Finding a filetype in current directory and subdirectory, including hidden files. (Homework)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, find, ubuntu-14.04

With bash, I am needing to find all gifs in my current directory and subdirectories, and display them in a specific way. I have to include hidden files as well, and I am not allowed to use grep (or its subsidiaries - fgrep and such) or basename. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 through a virtual machine (VirtualBox via Vagrant if that matters) without a GUI. My current script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -a | find $directory -type f -name "*.gif" | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev | cut -d. -f1 | sort -f
```

This has mostly done what I need, especially with regard to formatting, but when I changed one of the gifs to a hidden file, it was no longer visible - there was an extra empty line, almost as if the file name was written in invisible ink. Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: Piping `ls -a` into `find $directory ...` doesn't make any sense. `find` doesn't use the standard input. `find` will locate the hidden files anyway. And, by the way, `cut -d. -f1` will make any line starting with `.` into a blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

As lurker said in the comments `cut -d. -f1` will make any line starting with a `.` be a blank line.

From your code, the closest I could think of is

```
find $directory -type f -iname '*.gif' | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d. -f2,3 | rev | sort -f
```

Giving you all gifs, hidden or not, without path or extension.

#### Example

```
user@host /tmp % ls -aR
.:
.  ..  subdirectory  .test.gif  test.gif

./subdirectory:
.  ..  .sub.gif  sub.gif
user@host /tmp % find . -type f -iname '*.gif' | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d. -f2,3 | rev | sort -f
sub
.sub 
test
.test
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using 
    -name "*.gif"
which also worked for my purposes - I suppose -iregex may be better to use in the future?